# Yii2 Dropdown list value in controller

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a dropdown list in my view and would like to send an email later from controller

create view:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'company')->dropDownList(['a' => 'LG', 'b' => 'Samsung'], ['prompt'=>''])->label('Company');
```

action code:

```
public function actionVacancy()
{
    $model=new VacancyForm;

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&$model->validate())
    {

      Yii::$app->mailer->compose('vacancy',[
                        ...
                        'company'=> $model->company,
                        ...
      ])
```

What is the proper way to access dropdown list selected value? Currently I can only access key, but don't understand how to access value

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your controller action put print_r($_POST);exit() then when you submit a form you'll see the value in the post array and know how to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you need to load the POST values into the model before you can access them.

```
$model = new Model();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

//send email
$company = $model->company

...
```

Comment: POST values are loaded.the problem is that $model->company returns 'a' and I don't know how to get 'LG' e.g. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: LG won't be sent in the form, it's a key => value and only the key is sent, if you want LG from a you'll either have to set up a relation for it or set LG to be your key as well as your value. Your relation would be something like $model->company->lg_table. Good link on it http://blog.hashsolutions.in/technology/yii2-need-know-part-iii-activerecord/

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you obtain the result of the POST. In this case you get the value of the id related with your dropdown because this is value send by post.

If you want obtain the description in controller yon need `find` the descriptio related to the model by id.

```
 use yourapp\models\Company;

 $company = Company::find()
->where(['id' => $model->company])
->one();
```

assuming $ model->company contains the id of the istance you are looking for

```
  $company->name  //
```

should contain the desired value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer